# How to pass event to a child in LitElement

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element, lit-html

I want to make a drop-down menu and that when clicking on the input, the menu is displayed with a toggle that removes or places the 'hidden' class

I have this method

```
toggleMenu() {
    this.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

And here the template.

```
render(){
   return html`
       <input @click="${this.toggleMenu}" type="button">
       <ul class="hidden">
           <slot></slot>
       </ul>
   `;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what the question is. Are you asking how to toggle the `hidden` class on the `<ul>` element?

Comment: the question is very valid, but everyone below only answered the class part, not event passing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One straightforward solution is to add a property to your custom element, e.g. `open`, that is toggled in your `toggleMenu` method:

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    open: { type: Boolean },
  };
}

constructor() {
  super();
  this.open = false;
}

toggleMenu() {
  this.open = !this.open;
}
```

Then in your `render` method set the `<ul>`'s `class` attribute based on the value of `this.open`:

```
render(){
  return html`
    <button @click=${this.toggleMenu} type="button">Toggle</button>
    <ul class=${this.open ? '' : 'hidden'}>
      <slot></slot>
    </ul>
  `;
}
```

You can see this working in the below snippet:

```js
// import { LitElement, css, html } from 'lit-element';
const { LitElement, css, html } = litElement;

class DropDownMenu extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      open: { type: Boolean },
    };
  }

  static get styles() {
    return css`
      ul.hidden {
        display: none;
      }
    `;
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.open = false;
  }
  
  toggleMenu() {
    this.open = !this.open;
  }

  render(){
    return html`
      <button @click=${this.toggleMenu} type="button">Toggle</button>
      <ul class=${this.open ? '' : 'hidden'}>
        <slot></slot>
      </ul>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('drop-down-menu', DropDownMenu);
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/lit-element@2.2.1"></script>

<drop-down-menu>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</drop-down-menu>
```

If you want to apply additional classes to the `<ul>` you'll want to look into the `classMap` function as described [in the LitElement docs](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#dynamic-classes-and-styles).

---

Alternatively, you can add `reflect: true` to the `open` property declaration, which lets you show or hide the `<ul>` using CSS alone, rather than setting its `class` in `render`:

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    open: {
      type: Boolean,
      reflect: true,
    },
  };
}

static get styles() {
  return css`
    ul {
      display: none;
    }
    :host([open]) ul {
      display: block;
    }
  `;
}
```

Here it is in a working snippet:

```js
// import { LitElement, css, html } from 'lit-element';
const { LitElement, css, html } = litElement;

class DropDownMenu extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      open: {
        type: Boolean,
        reflect: true,
      },
    };
  }

  static get styles() {
    return css`
      ul {
        display: none;
      }
      :host([open]) ul {
        display: block;
      }
    `;
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.open = false;
  }
  
  toggleMenu() {
    this.open = !this.open;
  }

  render(){
    return html`
      <button @click=${this.toggleMenu} type="button">Toggle</button>
      <ul>
        <slot></slot>
      </ul>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('drop-down-menu', DropDownMenu);
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/lit-element@2.2.1"></script>

<drop-down-menu>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</drop-down-menu>
```

Both of these are common approaches and the best one for your application will depend on your use case and personal preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep it simple, if you need a reference to the DOM node then pass the event to the function like the following:

```js
toggleMenu(ev) {
    ev.target.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

And for the render method

```js
render(){
   return html`
       <input @click="${(ev)=>{this.toggleMenu(ev)}}" type="button">
       <ul class="hidden">
           <slot></slot>
       </ul>
   `;
}
```

And you're done

Comment: Generally we recommend using the template as much as possible and avoiding imperative DOM mutations.

Comment: @JustinFagnani I understand your point and this is usually what I'd do if I have reactivity in the application (like I am using React, Preact ...) I assumed OP doesn't have that. Or maybe reactivity can be added without them if you an elaborate I will be grateful.